# How to remove space between button and input

Tags: html, css

this is the html code here is not css and it has space between the button and input search

```
<div class="search-engine-container">
   <i class="search icon"></i>
   <input type="text" id="search_input" placeholder="...البحث عن المنتجات">
   <button id="clear-search-engine">x</button>
</div>
```

**this how it looks like**

[image]

Comment: Remove the white space characters (spaces and new lines) between the tags in the HTML.

Comment: you are not saying much if you don't include the css. Anyway maybe set margin: 0 on both elements (input and button)?

Comment: Include CSS if you want us to be able to show you whats wrong here.

Comment: in the css I m only setting ```border: 1px solid blue``` to search-engine-container

Answer (score 4):

an idea can be to use position of button inside container

if container position is relative you can set button to position absolute

```css
.search-engine-container {
  position: relative;
}

.search-engine-container button {
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-engine-container">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
        <input type="text" id="search_input" placeholder="...البحث عن المنتجات">
        <button id="clear-search-engine">x</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display: flex;` to your `.search-engine-container` class.

```css
.search-engine-container {
  display:flex;  
}
```

```html
<div class="elm"></div>
<div class="search-engine-container">
    <i class="search icon"></i>
    <input type="text" id="search_input" placeholder="...البحث عن المنتجات">
    <button id="clear-search-engine">x</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A way is seting margin:

```css
button{
  margin: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-engine-container">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
        <input type="text" id="search_input" placeholder="...البحث عن المنتجات">
        <button id="clear-search-engine">x</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**the probem was in the white space**
We can remove white space by setting parent element font-size to 0 and child elements font-size to 17px

Answer (score -1):

The space is probably because of the margin around the input or around the button to remove it use the code below:

```
#search_input {
    margin: 0;
}
#clear-search-engine {
    margin: 0;
}
```

If this didn't work then the problem isn't because of margin but you still can fix it using margin:

```
#search_input {
        margin-right: -5px;
}
```

And you can adjust the number of pixels as you want.

Comment: no there is no margin it's because the white space I fix it think you :)